# /proc/PID/sched measure units

Tags: linux, proc, scheduling

Does anyone know what are the measurement units for the metrics in `/proc/<PID>/sched` file in Linux?

```
cat /proc/1277/sched
flush-202:32 (1277, #threads: 1)
---------------------------------------------------------
se.exec_start                      :    7969759448.265086
se.vruntime                        :     282810360.009524
se.sum_exec_runtime                :        121710.613450
se.statistics.wait_start           :             0.000000
se.statistics.sleep_start          :    7969759448.265086
se.statistics.block_start          :             0.000000
se.statistics.sleep_max            :          5005.885001
se.statistics.block_max            :          9270.821298
se.statistics.exec_max             :             3.988085
se.statistics.slice_max            :            12.407345
se.statistics.wait_max             :            12.008414
se.statistics.wait_sum             :         11067.153244
se.statistics.wait_count           :              1611854
se.statistics.iowait_sum           :         12593.039209
se.statistics.iowait_count         :                    2
se.nr_migrations                   :                17755
se.statistics.nr_migrations_cold   :                    0
se.statistics.nr_failed_migrations_affine:                    0
se.statistics.nr_failed_migrations_running:                58593
se.statistics.nr_failed_migrations_hot:                    2
se.statistics.nr_forced_migrations :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups           :              1593915
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_sync      :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_migrate   :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_local     :              1593912
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_remote    :                    3
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_affine    :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_affine_attempts:                    3
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_passive   :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_idle      :                    0
avg_atom                           :             0.076350
avg_per_cpu                        :             6.855004
nr_switches                        :              1594100
nr_voluntary_switches              :              1593916
nr_involuntary_switches            :                  184
se.load.weight                     :                 1024
policy                             :                    0
prio                               :                  120
clock-delta                        :                  129
```

whereas the counts are pretty much self explanatory, the times are not. Is it seconds, millisecond or microseconds?
I'm especially interested in

```
se.statistics.iowait_sum           :         12593.039209
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are displayed in milliseconds; they’re tracked in nanoseconds, and scaled by one million (see [`kernel/sched/debug.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched/debug.c)). So

```
se.statistics.iowait_sum           :         12593.039209
```

means the process spent just over 12.5 seconds in I/O wait.